# Jhispter doesn't respond for 3 mins after this message - WARNING! git is not found on your computer

Tags: jhipster

I am new to JHipster, I am seeing a weird issue. JHipster getting stuck for atleast 3 mins to ask the first question (i.e application type). However when I kill the node.exe process in task manager it will start the question. any help on this is appreciated.

```
jhipster --skip-git --skip-insight --skip-cache
```

Comment: you fail to specify what exactly are you trying to accomplish, as you are new to JHIpster, do you really know what that command does?

Answer (score 0):

the code you put actually eliminates the modules from jhipster but jhipster uses git modules for generating applications so its preferrable to install git.